# how to write a JUnit test that can see my EJB service?

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, ejb

I have a Java EE application running on WebSphere 7 (using IBM RAD 7.5 / Eclipse).

It's basically user.JSP -> UserServlet -> @Stateless UserService -> UserDAO -> Oracle

I want to write some JUnit tests for the UserService.

I launch the application from within Eclipse, it's running on WebSphere.  I have a JUnit test in a new Java project in Eclipse.  My question is, how can my JUnit test access a reference to UserService?

Is there a way for me to do something like with an @EJB annotation:

```
public class UserTests extends TestCase {

  @EJB  
  private UserServiceLocal userService;

  public void test1() throws Exception {
    Assert.assertTrue("userService is not null", (userService != null));
  }

}
```

Here's a basic version of my UserService:

```
@Stateless
public class UserService implements UserServiceLocal {

  @EJB
  private UserDAOLocal userDAO;

  /* ... */
}
```

NOTE: @EJB doesn't inject anything.

NOTE: `userService = (UserServiceLocal)new InitiatContext().lookup(UserServiceLocal.JNDI);` doesn't work either, says, "NamingManager.getURLContext cannot find the factory for this scheme: ejblocal"

```
@Local
public class interface UserServiceLocal {

  public static final String JNDI = "ejblocal:com.myapp.service.UserServiceLocal";

  /* ... */
}
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, my solution was I added a remote EJB interface to the EJBs I want to test from JUnit.

I created a new "Application Client Project" and put my JUnit tests in there.  My JUnit tests do a remote lookup of the EJB.  Seems to work okay.

However, using WebSphere 7, I had to use the createEJBStubs command to generate the required stubs.  More details here and here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21393419

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Frejb_3stubscmd.html

Comment: are you still using this solution or did you move to Arquillian? In that case, I would like to ask how you handle the dependencies that exist within your EJBs.

Answer (score 2):

Please use an embedded container to solve your issue, or consider using Arquilian for this task. 
Arquillian will let your build a "Java EE deployment" on the fly (i.e - via code) and deploy it using [Arquilian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html)  to your Application server, so you will be able to run JUnit, and actually run code on your server via your JUnit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have create a [maven-plugin wrapper](https://github.com/lsiu/websphere-maven-plugin) for the createEJBStub script.

**Why?**

This allow us to build test maven projects which runs as part of our CI setup against our application after deployment.

More specifically together with maven, this allow our test project to:

1. Utilize Maven dependency management to pull the API jar which we publish to our internal nexus repository
2. Create Stub classes as part of the "generate-sources" maven life-cycle
3. Run junit test case against Application server with EJB to do integration testing.